# Which database for good, standard full-text searching abilities

Tags: database, full-text-search

I've been using MySQL happily for many years but have now come across an issue using it and wondered where I should go from here. My issue is full-text indexing. MySQL just doesn't perform well using this feature with large tables, unless you use a third-party plugin like Lucene etc.

I don't mind paying for the database but would prefer a free service. I don't have a DB administration team that can maintain it, it's just me, so it has to be simple to maintain, develop and scale. I develop on a Windows IIS7 environment, usually in ASP.NET and Classic ASP. My application will probably have a maximum of 10 million rows in the full-text table, so not huge but fairly hefty.

I could quite easily grab Lucene and use that with MySQL, but I would really like to know which DB performs best using full-text indexing, straight out of the box, so-to-speak?

Any suggestions or experiences would be marvelous.

Comment: For the person who voted to close: I don't believe this is a closable question. If I had of written "Which DB?", in general, I could understand that, as it would solicit a debate. I am asking which DB is best to use for a particular function, which only a few people out there that continuously write full-text queries will know about.

Comment: You're still going to get a bunch of answers recommending Person X's favourite database, regardless of whether or not it's the "best".

Comment: @skaffman: I think you're wrong. MySQL is my all-time favourite database... but I'd never recommend it to others for full-text indexing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cant help a lot other than saying that [full text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) on sql server is amazing. It seems complicated at first (because of catalogs, indexes end everything) but once you give it a go you'll see thats quite simple to implement. [This](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/) website shows an example with screens

you also have several functions to manipulate (search) the data (the saurus, stoplists, etc..)

Comment: the table I used it was not very big 800k rows in average but the thing is the data I was querying was, lets say, very peculiar.  It was direct input from user on a website that sells one particular kind of product, so you can imagine how many forms the users had to say the same thing. My problem was not querying a large amount of data, it was finding the correct information inside a few thousands rows. So I deeply used stop words and functions like the saurus or inflexional

Answer (score 0):

[Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html).

In addition, there are [Ruby gems](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=pg_search) to take advantage of it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I worked at a place that used Oracle for full-text search, and they were happy with that until they found Lucene -- now they are switching to Lucene.

I've heard good things about Postgres' full-text search, but I've never seen it in action.

Lucene.NET is a straight .NET port of Lucene, and performs well.